# Not getting any data in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

i have created a class named `clsLoadPersonalExp` and code for getting data in my form. my problem is that i am not getting any data in my gridview. when i put same code in form, it is working fine. i think there is any problem in returning data back through class but i dont know how to fix.
here is my `clsLoadPersonalExp` class code

```
class clsLoadPersonalExp
    {
        public static SqlConnection con;
        public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        public static SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        public static DataSet ds;
        //public static int status_id;

        public static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FazalConstructions.Properties.Settings.ConnString"].ConnectionString;

        public static DataSet selectData()
        {
                    con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblPersonalExp", con);
                    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "DATA");                  
                    return ds;       
            }
        }
    }
```

and i am getting this data in my form as

```
ExpDgv.DataSource = clsLoadPersonalExp.selectData();
```

tell me where is the error please!

Comment: Could you post the code from your form as well?

Comment: i am accessing code at form as ExpDgv.DataSource = clsLoadPersonalExp.selectData();  as i have posted at last of the question

Comment: are you binding the data after returning it? call ExpDgv.DataBind() after you get the DataSource

Comment: Agree with above, make sure you call DataBind

Comment: i think databinding is used for grid in Asp.Net, by the way i am getting this after binding data 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I might be wrong. But is Gridview not based on an collection, simmiliar to ListView. There for you have to set ItemSource Property. When you do Binding using Xaml, you need an ObservableCollection. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Writing** it as follows.. hope it will Help you out!

```
ExpDgv.DataSource = (clsLoadPersonalExp.selectData()).Tables[0];
```